# Can't read text in web forms since firefox uses dark theme by default

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes

Since a couple of years, I have the dark desktop theme by default. Since I upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 a week ago, firefox upgraded with it, and it now uses a dark theme as well. That's okay with me, except for the fact that a fair number of web forms now have become unreadable: the text is white, but the form fields are white as well, so you can't see what you're typing.

Workaround: select the text after you've typed it, then it becomes visible and you can inspect it.

Other workaround: type everything in gedit and copy-paste it from there.

Sure, there are workarounds, but this is very annoying. I like the dark theme so I prefer to keep using it, but for web forms it's just not a good idea.

Is it possible to keep the dark theme but fix its behavior in web forms such that they are always readable?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue. You can find bug reports here:

[Bug 70315 - text in menus and boxes unreadable if using dark GTK theme](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70315)

[Bug 519763 - dark linux gtk theme makes pages look bad; "use system colors" should apply to input elements as well as fonts, or separate option needed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519763)

The suggested work around is to create a userContent.css file in your firefox profile as per [these instructions from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Tweaks#Unreadable_input_fields_with_dark_GTK.2B_themes).

Comment: The linked page from Archwiki has now another option - to install "Text Contrast for Dark themes add-on from https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/text-contrast-for-dark-themes/ which worked great for me since it ensures contrast while retaining the colors the web-site sets and modifying only those that doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to edit the userContent.css for firefox. I had this issue previously with the Ubuntu Software center and did something similar.

You can find a related post about it here:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1703251&postcount=3

I am not sure if this fix still works since the 16.04 update, but it should be applicable.

Comment: This .css replacement fixes also badly rendered SVG's.